# Predefined type 'system.datatype' is not defined or imported (all datatypes)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget, mscorlib

My development was going fine until a few days ago. Whenever i had a Razor view open, the error list would give me trouble. The project would still compile. Now it stopped, and it gives the same error on all datatypes (System.void, System.int32, etc.). I have no idea why it is doing this all of a sudden. I tried updating VS2017 to no avail.

[image: a sample of the many "errors"]

I have seen others with the same problem, but they all have problems regarding a special extension/NuGet. Anyone else tried this? Also, `mscorlib` is not referenced as far as I can tell

I have two projects in this solution, it only throws these errors for my main project, the other one builds just fine

Comment: Does it happen in a brand new project?

Comment: have you checked your nuget package.config? this sounds like a reference issue there

Comment: @LaughingMan, if possible, please check this thread:https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/2243. If it not help you, could you please share us your project type and packages list, such as, packages.config.

Comment: I had the same issue just now and changing the Target framework to something else, saving, then changing it back did the trick. I tried other things before (like unload/reload, restart VS...), without success

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto it does, but goes away after a minute or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I saw there was a conflict with **mscorlib** and **System.Runtime**, but I did not have any references to the former. I tried removing my project's reference to **System.Runtime** and it worked! I don't know why it started acting up hundreds of hours into development

I would still very much like to know what causes this, so *please* share if you have similar experiences so we can avoid this in the future. Cheers

Comment: thanks for sharing your solution here, you could mark it as the answer before you get the better solution, so it could help other community members who get the same issues.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!